# Change data length of all occurrences of particular column

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We use an Oracle 11G database for our applications and one key field that is used everywhere is our part number field.  This is usually called:

```
PNID    (Part Number ID)
```

or

```
PNSNID  (Part Number Stock Number ID)
```

Either way it is named, it refers to the same thing.  Currently, the part number is 5 digits long (varchar2 (5) field) but we have an upcoming requirement to allow 8 digts (meaning we change it to varchar2 (8)).  Since manny tables, procedures, and functions use the 5-byte length, this can pose some problems.  I'm an analyst, not a developer but my part of the task is to identify the impact and effort of making such changes before anything gets assigned to a developer.  Essentially, I need to locate how many places it needs to be updated.

To find the tables that need updating was easy enough.  I queried dba_tab_columns to find all tables with a field named PNID or PNSNID and I was also able to pull the current length and datatype of the field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    owner,
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type,
    data_length
FROM
    dba_tab_columns
WHERE
    owner = 'APP_CORE'
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, 'PN[S]?[N]?ID');
```

But for locating the declarations in package bodies, procedures, and functions, I'm at a loss.   Searching through other stack overflow questions I found that I can query DBA_SOURCE and DBA_ARGUMENTS to find the instance of a string within the code but I don't think I'm approaching this correctly.

My DBA_SOURCE query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    owner,
    name,
    line,
    text
FROM
    dba_source
WHERE
    owner = 'APP_CORE'
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(text), 'PN[S]?[N]?ID\s+\S+\s*\(\d\)');
```

The regex string should find any PNID or PNSNID string foloowed by at least one space then any non-space character (for the data type declaration) then zero or more optional spaces followed by parenthesis with a number inside (the data length).  This is the best way that I could think of only finding lines that actually declare the length of the data type but there are over 1000 results returned and when checking each line, sometimes they are commented out or they decalre the data type from using %TYPE% by referring to the actually table data type (which would mean that I only have to alter that table and anything that uses that type would already be good to go).  The fact is that I can't possibly look through all 1000+ instances to find out if it is really in need of being changed.  Is there a better way to do this?

I did something similar for finding any functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    owner,
    package_name,
    object_name,
    arugument_name,
    data_type,
    default_length,
    in_out
FROM
    dba_arguments
WHERE
    owner = 'APP_CORE'
    AND (REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, 'PN[S]?[N]?ID')
    OR  REGEXP_LIKE(ARGUMENT_NAME, 'PN[S]?[N]?ID'))
ORDER BY
    1,2,3,4;
```

My question is, am I approaching this correctly?  We should only have to change the data length inside the tables then any place it is declared in the package bodies, procedures, and functions, right?  Is there anything I"m missing?  Also, is there a more accurate way to find all occurence I need to change (using only SQL Developer, I don't have TOAD)?

Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the variables are declared with anchored datatypes (e.g. `v_pnid some_table.pnid%type), then it's unlikely that you'd need to amend them in the code. It's only where the variables have been declared with explicit datatypes (e.g. v_pnid varchar2(5)) that you'll have to amend. Don't forget to check triggers (that'll be a part of dba_source). I wouldn't bother checking dba_arguments; you should find everything by searching dba_source. You've just got to hope that all variables/parameters related to the pn(sn)Id columns have the pn(sn)id as part of their name!

Comment: Just from a very quick reading, your first regexp_like seems incorrect. It will find the strings you want, but it will also find PNSID and PNNID. The correct regular expression to use is `'PN(SN)?ID'`. Then - can you explain again what the issue is? Are you looking for functions and such that may specifically allocate `varchar2(5)` to variables that will hold values coming from this column? If you do find any (showing poor coding habits), make sure their declarations are changed to something like `l_pnid MAIN_TABLE.PNIN%type`. This use case is exactly what this kind of declaration is for.

Comment: Why will not developers estimate this? I would divide it into two phases: the first phase - code review by programmers. Developers (not analysts) estimate how long this phase (code review) will take them. Then they do the code review. Once they know what and where the code will be changed, we estimate the second phase: corrections in the code, tests, and bug fixes. The second phase estimates the entire team: programmers, testers and analysts.